# Convert a standard JSON array into a 2d array object

Tags: ruby

In ruby, how would I parse this JSON into a 2d location array object?

I want to convert it to a simple object like this:

```
[["Seattle"]["Washington"],["Seaton"]["Illinois"]]
```

I tried a few things and having trouble with it and there are not very many examples of this that I could find via Google search.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "Washington",
            "zip": "98104",
            "country": "US",
            "empty": false,
            "county": null
        },
        {
            "city": "Seaton",
            "state": "Illinois",
            "zip": "61476",
            "country": "US",
            "empty": false,
            "county": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I tried so far  (which doesn't get me quite there):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
...
parsed = JSON.parse(string)
parsed["data"].each do |location|
  unless location["city"].nil?
    location.each do |location_item|
      puts location_item.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You have displayed a hash, but as it's actually a string, you should enclose it in single quotes. Also, It's helpful to assign a variable to it (e.g., `js = '{
    "data": [...}'`) so that readers can refer to the variable without having to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(string)['data'].map { |hash| [hash['city'], hash['state']] }
#=> [["Seattle", "Washington"],["Seaton","Illinois"]]
```

Comment: Thanks , that did it.  I cant believe it was that simple.  This will take some getting used to since I don't think that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'json'
```

Depending on your requirements,

```
JSON.parse(str)["data"].flat_map { |h| h.values_at("city", "state") }
  #=> ["Seattle", "Washington", "Seaton", "Illinois"]

or

JSON.parse(str)["data"].map { |h| h.values_at("city", "state") }
  #=> [["Seattle", "Washington"], ["Seaton", "Illinois"]]
```